# rlm_rest : Handling MSCHAP

Tags: freeradius

I'm writing a django based json rest service for use with rlm_rest.

FreeRadius will serve both AAA and DHCP.

Despite my scripting skill, The DHCP Part is working correctly ... but have problem with the authentication part.

My test scenario:

1. Using Radtest : Client got good response ... including the 'Framed-Pool'
2. Mikrotik PPPoe Server, Xubuntu PPPoE Client with All Auth Protocol enabled : Always Rejected, because my script Got no 'User-Password' only got MSCHAP-Challenge and MSCHAP-Response.
3. Mikrotik PPPoe Server, Xubuntu PPPoE Client with only PAP enabled : Success

   Here is what rlm_rest send to myscript :

   {"User-Name":{"type":"string","value":["dokter01"]},"NAS-IP-Address":{"type":"ipaddr","value":["10.255.255.2"]},"NAS-Port":{"type":"integer","value":[6]},"Service-Type":{"type":"integer","value":[2]},"Framed-Protocol":{"type":"integer","value":[1]},"Called-Station-Id":{"type":"string","value":["pppoe4"]},"Calling-Station-Id":{"type":"string","value":["08:00:27:B2:02:7E"]},"NAS-Identifier":{"type":"string","value":["mtik02"]},"NAS-Port-Type":{"type":"integer","value":[15]},"NAS-Port-Id":{"type":"string","value":["ether4"]},"MS-CHAP-Challenge":{"type":"octets","value":["0x85b513a5551084b06a801b240d5b77ea"]},"MS-CHAP2-Response":{"type":"octets","value":["0x0100f5707f4ee9b6bb6a99c5670b15ec789a0000000000000000af338d696f9bfc4e68549bb85940aaa95c8161a2e740f857"]}}

Could you please give me some clue ?

Sincerely

-bino-

Comment: What is it you want help with? This is not a programming site.

Comment: When I google for help on rlm_rest, I found it here.

Ok, if serverfault command me to delete it, I will do that.

I just want to know how to handle MSCHAP Chalenge and response while I only have username and password database.

Thankyou